# Failing to get attribute value in Python

Tags: python, findall, getattr

I'm trying to code a scraper for a website and so far I was able to scrape the general information I need but the specific attribute value I am trying to obtain from that information is returning with none even though there are clearly values there. 
It all works fine up until I try using getattr of each container in containers to find the values for data-id. Maybe there's a better way to do this but I'm having a hard time understanding why it's not able to find it.

This is what my code looks like.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "http://csgo.exchange/id/76561197999004010#x"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
import time
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
soup = soup(html, "html.parser")


containers = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"vItem"})
print(len(containers))

for container in containers:
    test = getattr(container, "data-id")

    print(str(test))


with open('scraped.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(containers))
```

Here's a sample of what each container looks like.

> div class="vItem Normal Container cItem" data-bestquality="0" data-category="Normal" data-collection="The Spectrum Collection" data-currency="0" data-custom="" data-exterior="" data-hashname="Spectrum%20Case" data-id="15631554103"

Comment: Why are you using `getattr`?? Presumably you picked this up from somewhere.

Comment: Well like I said I'm sure there are better methods but just from my research thus far that was the only method I came across that didn't confuse me. I'm assuming it's not a reliable thing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the line with `getattr()` to `container.attrs["data-id"]`. That works for me. But the 10 seconds time sleeps wasn't enough for me in most attempts.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "http://csgo.exchange/id/76561197999004010#x"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
import time
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
soup = soup(html, "html.parser")


containers = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"vItem"})
print(len(containers))
data_ids = [] # Make a list to hold the data-id's

for container in containers:
    test = container.attrs["data-id"]
    data_ids.append(test) # add data-id to the list

    print(str(test))


with open('scraped.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for id in data_ids:
        file.write(str(id)+'\n') # write every data-id to a new line.
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. I know the 10 second thing is just a placeholder atm. Eventually I want it to wait until the element is loaded before it scrapes the page but I'm not entirely sure how to do that yet. Problem with this site is it sometimes loads fast and other times it doesn't.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but how would I get those values stored in test into a global variable that I could write? Because right now it just writes one of them and not the others.

Comment: See the edit above. Just add the `test` variable to a list and then in the end, write all entries of the list to a file.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I'll try to take what I just learned and move forward.